# Correctly nesting If statements in For loops for R

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a new variable using information within another variable in my dataset.  This dataset contains 7 variables and over a million rows of data. Because of the size I thought it would be less difficult to create a new variable using an already existing variable with an if statement nested in a for loop as I want values for every iteration of the old variable.

The old variable is a categorical variable with 7 different values. Because of that I am trying to make 7 different variables with the the if statement. if the old variable = 1 the data point in the new variable = 1, if not 0. Same with the other variables

My code is as follows:

```
for (i in new_2001_2002_data$`Main Source of Power`) 
  {
  No_Power = 0
    if (new_2001_2002_data$`Main Source of Power`=1)
      {
      No_Power = 1 
      }
    else 
      {
      No_Power = 0
      }
  }
```

Yet I keep getting error messages all throughout the loop. I assume it has something to do with my usage of i, but that isnt the only problem

Answer (score 0):

Some potential mistakes:

- Inside your if statement, when we perform comparison, we should use "==" rather than "=".
- Note that your i variable is not used inside the loop.

Comment: I just realized that after the ability to edit the post was gone, Yes You are right in regard to the ==.

however, What should I do with the for statement so that I go through every iteration of the variable Main source of Power?

Comment: what is No_Power? is it a vector or a single variable?

Comment: No Power is meant to be the new variable I am attempting to create.

Comment: I would encourage you to check out the function ifelse. No loop is required.

Comment: actually, after some googling, I figured out an answer to my issue. I didnt need to do any looping as you've stated. I used a whithin statement which included an ifelse() statment in it.

Comment: that's awesome. congratulations.